# Transformation the inverse Gaussian probability distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, inverse-gaussian-distribution

Suppose $X$ has pdf $I(\mu, \tau)$ with density,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\tau}{2\pi x^{3}}}\exp\{-\frac{\tau}{2x\mu^{2}}(x-\mu)^2\}\quad; x>0, \quad \tau,\mu>0$$

I want to find the distribution of $V = \dfrac{\tau(x-\mu)^{2}}{x\mu^{2}}$.

My work: The distribution of $V$ can be written as follows.

$$f(v) = f_{X}(g^{-1}(v))\bigg|\frac{dg^{-1}(v)}{dv}\bigg|$$

Solving $x$ using $V$ we can find that $x - \dfrac{\mu^{2}}{x} = 2\mu + \dfrac{\mu^{2}v}{\tau} $.

So, my question is how to get x on one side of the equation (I have $\mu$ on my left hand side)? Are there any methods to derive the distribution of $V$?

Comment: Your last equation is a quadratic in $x$ (multiply by $x$ on both sides), so solve for $x$ using the well-known formula.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, Do I need to solve the quadratic equation in $x$ to find V? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. If $g(x)=v$, then $x=g^{-1}(v)$ (if the inverse exists). You have to find $x$ in terms of $v$ to apply the transformation formula.

Comment: I am afraid I missed this question and asked [the same.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/491872/7224) With the derivation that $V$ is a $\chi^1_1$ variate [provided as the answer.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/491993/7224)

Comment: Note that you cannot use the Jacobian formula here as $V$ is not a bijective transform of $X$. The trick consists in using first $Y=\min\{X,\mu^2/X\}$ and showing that$$W = \dfrac{\tau(Y-\mu)^{2}}{Y\mu^{2}}$$ has the same distribution as $V$ but is a bijective transform of $Y$.